# How to change the alpha blend amount with sideways transition?

Tags: keyframes, masking, blend-modes

I have this graphic in an [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-serial-communications-work-on-the-arduino) in another SE site:

[image: Source graphic]

It has been produced in Inkscape, and I can easily make various parts into separate PNG files (by using layers).

My objective is to make an animated GIF (or movie) where the **opacity of** the blue line which goes from Tx to Rx moves sideways over a couple of seconds, to indicate the data movement.

Thus, holding the rest of the image unchanged, the blue line (the one with the arrows) might start at 50% opacity, and smoothly turn to 100% opacity, from left to right.

So far I have the blue line in a separate PNG file, and the rest of the image in another one.

---

Arrow:

[image: Arrow]

The rest:

[image: Rest of graphic]

---

I made a mask, and keyframed its shape so that it gradually covers the area occupied by the area. But now I'm stuck.

I can't put it all together to get the effect I described.

So far I have this in the Video Editing layout:

[image: Video editing]

But:

- The mask affects both images
- It just makes the image white rather than change its opacity, like this:

[image: Mask result]

I've also tried various things in the Compositor without any real success.

---

Is there a simple and easy way of achieving this?

Comment: This is an extremely late partial answer but you may want to try this in the 3D view, create 2 planes for your two images, add another plane with a mask transparency, change the pivot point to the edge, keyframes the size and etc.

Comment: @Bradman175 That's helpful, thanks! I set up a plane with the first image, but am a bit unsure about making a mask transparency that moves sideways. Is there a link to a tutorial for doing that? Is it something you would do in the 3D view, or the Compositor?

Comment: When I have time, I will make a proper answer with some images.